# Extracting frames with ffmpeg - why are they three dimensions?

Tags: ffmpeg, extract, tiff, frames, idl

I have been using ffmpeg as an extremely useful tool in video processing for my research. One problem I have run into: when extracting frames from a video to a Tiff format, it saves each Tiff with **three** dimensions instead of the expected two (width x height of video frames).

When reading this into my IDL code, of course it balks at a Tiff image being a three dimensional array. The third dimension has a size of three, I think because I did my extraction at a framerate of 3 Hz (?). Does anybody know why ffmpeg doesn't create a simple Tiff image of two dimensions? Is there a way to force that?

Answer (score 1):

The third dimension is due to the color system being split into different channels.
So you got 2 dimensions for the image and one dimension for the red, green and blue channel.

for an image to be 2 dimensional you would need to convert it to grayscale, so that each 2d-pixelcell only contains one brightness value.

Comment: Typically, you would use COLOR_QUAN in IDL to create a 2-dimensional image plus color table from a 3-dimensional image. This process is not necessarily exact since color tables are limited to 256 colors and the 3-dimensional image may have many more colors.